# Animated transition from one GridView to another

Tags: animation, windows-8, microsoft-metro

A transition animation between various Cells of a `GridView` is simply possible with `RepositionThemeTransition`.

But in my case, I need to move `Element`s from one `GridView` to another one.

is it possible to animate a transition while moving an `Element` (e.g. an `Image`) from one `GridView` to another?